# Drupal 7 path_save with a query arguments

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-path-aliases

I've searched all over for examples of this, but I haven't found any.  I'm trying to create an alias for path which includes query arguments, like profile?arg1=113.

It doesn't matter if I provide `path_save()` with the plain string representation of the path, or if I provide it with `url()`.

```php
url('profile', array('query' => array('arg1' => $uid)))
```

Either way, *?* and *=* show up as escaped characters on the URL aliases admin page, which naturally means the path can't be found.

How can I keep the ? and = from being escaped?

**12/19/12 Edit 1:** the larger context is that I'm trying to set up the alias when a [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) profile is being saved (i.e., in mymodule_profile2_presave()) - that's when I'll have all the information I need to programmatically set up the alias.

**12/19/12 Edit 2:** I just realized that the problem isn't on the insert side - the url_alias table actually has unescaped characters in it.  The problem is that Drupal doesn't urldecode the path before using it...

**12/20/12 Edit 3:** Found a solution using [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) instead of path aliases.  Redirect properly decodes the query string!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach the query string to the destination of an alias. The code executed from [drupal_path_initialize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_path_initialize/7) doesn't handle the query string correctly.

The function contains the following code.

```php
$_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET['q']);
```

Suppose that you have "example" as path alias that points to "node/93?uid=1"; that code would set `$_GET['q']` to `'node/93?uid=1'`, while you are expecting `$_GET['q']` to get `'node/93'`, and `$_GET['uid']` to be set to `1`.

What you could do is implementing [hook_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) with code similar to the following one.

```php
function mymodule_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {
  list ($path, $query) = explode('?', $path);
  $_GET += drupal_get_query_array($query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, @kiamlaluno, but unfortunately, hook_inbound_alter() is not invoked with the alias I'm creating when I call path_save() - at least, in the context in which I'm calling it.  The larger context is that I'm trying to set up the alias when a [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) profile is being saved (i.e., in mymodule_profile2_presave()) - that's when I'll have all the information I need to programmatically set up the alias.  I added mymodule_url_inbound_alter(), but it is only invoked with the path for editing the user's profile when I save that profile.

Comment: I am sorry; I was not clear in that part. `hook_inbound_alter()` is used to alter a URL before it is used from Drupal. The code I am using is used to change a path like node/93?uid=1 to node/93, and to set `$_GET['uid'] to 1. It is not used to alter what `path_save()` saves, but it avoids a path like node/93?uid=1 is used to look for a node with ID equal to 93?uid=1.

Comment: no problem.  I should have provided the larger context when I made my original post (I'll add that info to the post right now).